# slim Authorization is not working after a while

Tags: php, slim

i have implemented an slim api for my application that get a api_key in header 
to get valid request 
this is the code

```
function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route) {
// Getting request headers
$headers = apache_request_headers();
$response = array();
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

// Verifying Authorization Header
if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
    $db = new DbHandler();
     global $api_key;
    // get the api key
    $api_key = $headers['Authorization'];
    // validating api key
    if (!$db->isValidApiKey($api_key)) {
        // api key is not present in users table
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Access Denied. Invalid Api key";
        echoRespnse(401, $response);
        $app->stop();
    } else {
        global $user_id;
        // get user primary key id
        $user_id = $db->getUserId($api_key);
    }
} else {
    // api key is missing in header
    $response["error"] = true;
    $response["message"] = "Api key is misssing";
    echoRespnse(400, $response);
    $app->stop();
}
```

}
it was working Properly  but suddenly without any change in my code i'am getting apikey is missing  Although i am Adding  Authorization in header now if i change Authorization to Authorizationn or some thing else it will work again but im afraid that after a while i get smae  error for new address again . now the qustion is is there any limit for one particular address in header in the the hostes or dose any one know why it's happening

Comment: What are you using to test your request?

Comment: postman on google chroom and my app in android both of them give me api key is missing !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Authorization has a value of your API Key.[image]

Comment: tanx dear  my authroization has the value of api key :(

Comment: Make sure that in your Postman Authorization starts with Uppercase A not lowercase a

Comment: i have checked all of them actually it just started to toast api key is missing without any change in my code